# Flutter plugin: "Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread."

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am creating Flutter plugin. There are few channels on which I am sending the callbacks from Android to Flutter. Situation is that I am listening for some events which are triggered in OTHER thread than main UI thread.

After recent Flutter update I starting to receive such an error

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 9400): FATAL EXCEPTION:  STARTING
E/AndroidRuntime( 9400): Process: com.northernbitcoin.coinyacapp, PID: 9400
E/AndroidRuntime( 9400): java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread:  STARTING
E/AndroidRuntime( 9400):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.ensureRunningOnMainThread(FlutterJNI.java:794)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9400):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.dispatchPlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:684)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9400):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.send(DartMessenger.java:80)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9400):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor.send(DartExecutor.java:174)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9400):    at io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView.send(FlutterNativeView.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9400):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel$IncomingStreamRequestHandler$EventSinkImplementation.success(EventChannel.java:226)
...
```

Only information I found is here
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34993

Yes, there are a solution here
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34993#issue-459900986

But it looks like too overhead for me, because I dont't want to create new `handler` for each my event

Is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 5):

Do the same as in suggested solution above, but use it for particular events only.

Create ui handler object

```java
public class BitcoinWalletPlugin implements MethodCallHandler, ... {

  private Handler uiThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

  @Override
  public void onListen(Object o, EventChannel.EventSink eventSink) {
    switch (this.channel) {
      ...
      case CHANNEL_NAME:
        // before
        // bitcoinWallet.setOnStartupListener(() -> eventSink.success(true));

        // after
        bitcoinWallet.setOnStartupListener(() -> uiThreadHandler.post(() -> eventSink.success(true)));
        break;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Kotlin you can wrap callback indide`runOnUiThread`

```
runOnUiThread {
    result.success(identifier);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/yongjhih/e6c5634c775e49f01c71ee029d8beebf:

```
fun Result.onMain(): ResultOnMain {
  return if (this is ResultOnMain) {
      this
  } else {
    ResultOnMain(this)
  }
}

class ResultOnMain internal constructor(private val result: Result) : Result {
  private val handler: Handler by lazy {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
  }

  override fun success(res: Any?) {
    handler.post { result.success(res) }
  }

  override fun error(
          errorCode: String, errorMessage: String?, errorDetails: Any?) {
    handler.post { result.error(errorCode, errorMessage, errorDetails) }
  }

  override fun notImplemented() {
    handler.post { result.notImplemented() }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "runOnUiThread" in your plugin, like this:

```
private Activity activity;

@Override
public void onAttachedToActivity(@NonNull ActivityPluginBinding binding) {
    activity = binding.getActivity();
}

public method()
{
  BasicMessageChannel channel = new BasicMessageChannel(messenger, CHANNEL, 
  JSONMessageCodec.INSTANCE);

  activity.runOnUiThread(() ->
   channel.send("");
  });
}
```