# i build an app to detect ibeacons but it show an error during runtime and terminate the searching

Tags: android, flutter, ibeacon, beacon

so I am trying to build an indoor navigation system and started with detecting the ibeacons so here is my code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_beacon/flutter_beacon.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  StreamSubscription<RangingResult>? _streamRanging;
  final _regionBeacons = <Region, List<Beacon>>{};
  final _beacons = <Beacon>[];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Request location permission
    requestPermission();
  }

  void requestPermission() async {
    if (await Permission.location.request().isGranted) {
      // Location permission granted
      initBeacon();
    } else {
      // Location permission denied
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Location Permission Required'),
          content: Text(
              'Please grant location permission to enable beacon scanning.'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                // Open app settings to allow the user to grant permission manually
                openAppSettings();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  // FlutterBeacon.initialize();
  initBeacon() async {
    try {
      await flutterBeacon.initializeScanning;
      //debugPrint('Beacon scanner initialized');
      print('Beacon scanner initialized');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    // Configure the regions to scan for iBeacons
    final regions = <Region>[];
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      regions.add(Region(
          identifier: 'MyBeacon',
          proximityUUID: 'a86be991-76c7-4fc4-892a-551acf07c77c',
          major: null,
          minor: null));
    } else {
      regions.add(Region(
          identifier: 'com.beacon',
          proximityUUID: 'a86be991-76c7-4fc4-892a-551acf07c77c',
          major: null,
          minor: null));
    }
    flutterBeacon.monitoring(regions).listen((MonitoringResult result) {
      // result contains a region, event type and event state
    });
    // Start ranging for beacons
    _streamRanging =
        flutterBeacon.ranging(regions).listen((RangingResult result) {
      if (result != null && result.beacons.isNotEmpty) {
        // Get a list of beacons in range
        List<Beacon> beacons = result.beacons;
        // Clear the list of beacons to remove any previous entries
        //_beacons.clear();
        //List<Map<String, dynamic>> detectedBeacons = [];
        // Iterate through beacons and get their data
        for (var beacon in beacons) {
          if (beacon.proximityUUID == 'a86be991-76c7-4fc4-892a-551acf07c77c') {
            String uuid = beacon.proximityUUID;
            int major = beacon.major;
            int minor = beacon.minor;
            int rssi = beacon.rssi;
            // Add beacon data to the list
            //detectedBeacons.add(
            //  {'uuid': uuid, 'major': major, 'minor': minor, 'rssi': rssi});

            setState(() {
              _beacons.clear();
              _beacons.addAll(beacons);
            });
            // Do something with beacon data
            // print(
            //   'Beacon detected: UUID=$uuid, major=$major, minor=$minor, rssi=$rssi');
            //   String uuid = beacon.proximityUUID;
            //   int major = beacon.major;
            //   int minor = beacon.minor;
            //   int rssi = beacon.rssi;
            //   // Do something with beacon data
            
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    // Stop ranging for beacons
    _streamRanging?.cancel();
    flutterBeacon.close;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'iBeacon Detection',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('iBeacon Detection'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _beacons.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            Beacon beacon = _beacons[index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('UUID: ${beacon.proximityUUID}'),
              subtitle: Text('Major: ${beacon.major}, Minor: ${beacon.minor}'),
              trailing: Text('RSSI: ${beacon.rssi}'),
              // body: Center(
              // child: Text('Searching for iBeacons...'),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here what it show me in the debug console
[image]
[image]

[image]

and I am using huwawei p30 pro to test the code. also I added all the needed permission in the manifest file
so what I can do to solve this issue, I get stuck here for a week

Comment: This is the error: "Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread."

Comment: how to solve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447702/flutter-plugin-methods-marked-with-uithread-must-be-executed-on-the-main-thre

Comment: i saw this solution but didn't understand where to add the uithread in my code, i am totaly new to this